# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be the $N\times N$ skew-symmetric matrix defined by the rules
$$\begin{cases}A_{ij}=1 & \text{when }i<j, \\ A_{ii}=0 & \forall i=1,...,N \\ A_{ij}=-1 &\text{when }i>j.\end{cases}$$ Can we derive a rule to write the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix as a function of $N$? What about a rule for determining its exponential?

For low values of $N$, it seems manageable: for example if $N=2$ we have the conjugate pair of eigenvalues $\lambda=i, \lambda^*=-i$, while for $N=3$ the eigenvalues are $\{0, \pm i\sqrt3\}$. Numerically, things seem to get complicated as soon as $N\ge 7$ however.

Comment: Let $\alpha=\exp(i\pi/n)$ and $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1})$. Then $D^{-1}AD$ is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) whose eigenvalues and eigenvectors admit explicit formulae. The eigenvectors of $A$ are given by $DU$, where $U$ denotes the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT).

Comment: @user1551 Can this be applied to the problem of finding an explicit form of $e^A$?

Comment: In theory, yes. After obtaining a diagonalisation $A=(DU)\Lambda(DU)^{-1}$, the matrix exponential can be computed as $e^A=\exp\big((DU)\Lambda(DU)^{-1}\big)=DUe^\Lambda U^\ast D^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

I base my answer on the comment of user1551 so thanks to them for the idea.

### Transforming $A$ to a circulant matrix

Define $\alpha= \sqrt[N]{-1}$ $(= \exp(\pi i /N) )$ and $D = \mathrm{diag} (\alpha^1,\alpha^2 \dots ,\alpha^N )$. Note the slight difference to the definition in the comments. Then $C = D^{-1} A D$ is a circulant matrix.

For example for $N=3$ we have
$$ C = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & \sqrt[3]{-1} & \left(-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\\\left(-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} & 0 & \sqrt[3]{-1}\\\sqrt[3]{-1} & \left(-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} & 0\end{matrix}\right].
$$
And in general the first column $c$ of $C$ (which defines $C$ uniquely) is given by
$$
c(j) =
\begin{cases}
0, \quad \text{if $j=1$,}\\
 \exp( \pi i (N-j+1) /N), \quad \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
Define the Fourier matrix $\mathcal{F} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ by $\mathcal{F}(j,k)= \exp(-2\pi i jk /N ) $.

Then we have
$$C= \mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathrm{diag}(\mathcal{F}c) \mathcal{F}, \tag{1}$$
see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Other_properties) (note the wrong factor of $1/N$ on wikipedia).

### Eigenvalues

From equation $(1)$ we obtain the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ as
\begin{align}
\lambda_j& = \sum_{k=1}^N \mathcal{F}(j,k) c(k) =  \sum_{k=2}^N \exp(-2 \pi i (j-1)(k-1) /N ) \exp( \pi i (N-k+1) /N) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \exp( \pi i  [k(1-2j)+N]/N).
\end{align}

In the case $N=3$ we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 &= \exp(2\pi i/3 )+ \exp(\pi i/3) = i \sqrt{3}, \\
\lambda_2 &= 1+  \exp(-\pi i) = 0, \\
\lambda_3 &= \exp(-2\pi i/3 )+  \exp(-7\pi i/3) = - i \sqrt{3}, \\
\end{align*}
which agrees with the result obtained using the usual methods.

I also numerically compared the formula with results for larger $N$ and it seems to give the correct results.

### Eigenvectors

From the above we have
$$A = D C D^{-1} = D \mathcal{F}^{-1} \mathrm{diag}(\mathcal{F}c) \mathcal{F} D^{-1}.$$
Therefore the eigenvector $v_j$ corresponding to $\lambda_j$ is given as the $j$-th column of $D \mathcal{F}^{-1} $.
We have $\mathcal{F}^{-1} (j,k) =1/N \mathcal{F}^*(j,k) = 1/N\exp(2\pi i jk /N )$ and therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
v_j (k) &= [D \mathcal{F}^{-1} ](k,j) = \sum_{l=1}^N D(k,l) \mathcal{F}^{-1}(l,j)  \\
&=1/N \exp(\pi i k/N) \exp(2\pi i (k-1)(j-1) /N )\\
&= 
1/N\exp(\pi i  (2kj-2j+2-k) /N ) \\
&= 1/N\exp(\pi i  (2j(k-1)+2-k) /N ).
\end{align*}
$$
For $N=3$ we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
v_1 = 1/3
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(\pi i  1 /3 ) \\
\exp(\pi i  2 /3 ) \\
\exp(\pi i  3/3 ) \\
\end{pmatrix},
\
v_2 = 1/3
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(\pi i  1 /3 ) \\
\exp(\pi i  4/3 ) \\
\exp(\pi i  7/3 ) \\
\end{pmatrix},
\
v_3 =  1/3
\begin{pmatrix}
\exp(\pi i  1 /3 ) \\
\exp(\pi i  6 /3 ) \\
\exp(\pi i  11/3 ) \\
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
$$
which can be checked to be the eigenvectors of $A$ to the eigenvalues found above.

I also verified this formula numerically for higher $N$ and it seems to work.

The matrix exponential can also be obtained in closed form from this. I leave the details to you.